# Can I use karma to launch a test server?

Tags: testing, karma-runner, karma-mocha

I have setup testing locally using Karma, Mocha and Chai, whenever I run

```
karma start
```

I get a webserver running locally:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.31 server started at http://localhost:9876/
```

I can then go to http://localhost:9876 using any browser I have and see how my tests run on that browser.

Is it possible to launch karma testing on a remote server so me and my collegues can access it with various browsers, without each one of us having to run karma locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turned out i just had to open port 9876 on the server, then me and my colleagues were able to access the tests with:

```
http://url.test.server:9876
```